# Python: How to remove values from a list that have a valence lower than a certain value

Tags: python, mysql, arcgis

In ArcGis I want to calculate the connectivity of a road network that I have drawn. Therefore, I give a valence to each road intersection based on the amount of streets that intersect each other. However, under the current circumstances, the toolbox would also includes two lines (e.g. in a curve) that are connected to each other with a valence of 2. I need to remove all values of the list that have a valence < 3, but since I barely have experience with programming, I do not know how to do this properly. Below is the piece of code from the toolbox for the calculation of the vertex layer.

```
#----------------------------------
#Begin of calculating valence field
gp.addmessage("Begin of calculating valence field")
#----------------------------------

#Make layer of vertices
#----------------------
gp.addmessage("Make layer of vertices")
desc=gp.Describe(inline)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName
thesr=desc.SpatialReference
gp.CreateFeatureClass(gp.workspace,vert, "Point","", "ENABLED", "DISABLED", thesr)
gp.addfield(vert, "valence", "short")
listk=[]
rows=gp.SearchCursor(inline) 
row = rows.Next()
while row:
    feat = row.GetValue(shapefieldname)
    partnum=0
    partcount=feat.PartCount
    print partcount
    while partnum < partcount:
        part = feat.GetPart(partnum)
        pnt = part.Next()
        pntcount = 0
        thex=pnt.x
        they=pnt.y
        thekey=(thex*1000000)+they
        while pnt:
            if thekey not in listk:
                cur = gp.InsertCursor(vert)
                rowvert = cur.NewRow()
                rowvert.shape = pnt
                cur.InsertRow(rowvert)
                listk.append(thekey)
            pnt = part.Next()
            pntcount += 1
        partnum += 1
    row=rows.next()
del row, rows, cur

# Remove all values valence < 3
#-------------------------------
```

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: This question should be moved to http://gis.stackexchange.com/. Could anyone vote for migration, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, if you have a list of values you can do

```
# Generate a random list for example.
import random
some_list = random.sample(range(30), 4)

# Keep elements greater than 3.
filtered_list = [value for value in some_list if value >= 3]

# The same outcome, another way to write it.
filtered_list = filter(lambda x: x >= 3, some_list)

# The same outcome, but written as a loop.
filtered_list = []
for value in some_list:
    if value >= 3:
        filtered_list.append(value)
```

It has been a while since I worked with ArcGIS/arcpy, but I am quite sure the FeatureClasses cannot be handled as easily as plain [Python lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). Regarding your arcpy code, you could use an [UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) to delete rows:

```
# Create an empty FeatureClass from the original.
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(your_feature_class) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row.valence <= 2:
            rows.deleteRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case, i would create a new list containing only the valence >= 3:

```
my_list = [1, 12, 4, 3, 7, 2, 0]
filtered_list = [val for val in my_list if val >= 3]
print filtered_list  # displays [12, 4, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function

```
 >>>filter(lambda x : x>3 , [1,2,3,4,5])
 [4,5]
```